# Power arduino board from ATX PSU?

Tags: arduino, atx

Can I power the Redboard Arduino board (basicly the same as Arduino Uno) from the + 12 V output from my ATX power supply? The specifications says the input voltage needs to be at least 7 V.

Is there anything I haven't thought of?

Comment: The normal disclaimer about Arduino on-board regulators applies, of course. But ATX power supplies provide 5V at a decent current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. The input range for your board is 7 to 15V. The tolerance for the ATX outputs is +-5%.

Comment: Thanks man. My worry was not the voltage, but the fact there is different voltage/current sources and that this could potentially pose problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. 12V DC is 12V DC, no matter where from. Of course you have to care about the current consumption (which will surely not be too high with only the arduino board) and a proper ground connection.

Comment: I've read that some IC's don't support multi-rail. Have no idea why and why it would matter. :P

Answer (score 1):

Many ATX supplies require a minimum load on *every* rail before they can maintain regulation. Verify that the supply you have doesn't require this, or alternatively put a high-power, moderate-to-low resistance between each rail and ground to allow the PSU to work properly.

Comment: All righty. I don't think this one will need that as it is a very expensive PSU, but good to know anyway. And maybe I'll run into problems with this, who knows.